# How do I write to a specific file/location with gawk close()

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
NameA X Y 0 Add1
NameA X Y 1 Add1
NameB X Y 1 Add1
NameB X Y 0 No
NameB X Y 1 No
```

and I'm running it through gawk as follows:

```
gawk -v OFS='\t' '{FS = OFS} {if ($0 ~ /Add1/) {print $2, $3, $4 + 1 >> $1; close($1)} else {print $2, $3, $4 >> $1; close($1)}}' input_file.txt
```

This writes 2 files "NameA" and "NameB" in the workdirectory and it works as I intend it to.

Is there a way to write these files to a specific directory, and append something like ".processed" so the files sit like this:

```
/some/dir/input_file.txt
/some/dir/processed/NameA.processed
/some/dir/processed/NameB.processed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just change:

```
… >> $1 …
```

To:

```
… >> "processed/"$1".processed" …
```

Comment: Wow, I was just missing the quotes while testing. Thank you!